# Function receiving null string

Tags: c, osdev

I have the following problem: I pass a string to a function, however, when it receives the string, it receives a null value and does nothing, I've been trying to solve it for days and nothing, I'm thinking it's a error in main() function

Here is my code:

```
void main(){
   clear_screen();
   print_string("Hello World!"); 
}


void print_string(const char *string){
   int offset = get_cursor();
   int i = 0;
   while (string[i] != 0) {
      if(offset >= ROWS * COLS * 2) {
         offset = scroll_line(offset);
      }
      if(string[i] == '\n') {
         offset = move_offset_to_new_line(offset);
      }else{
         print_char(string[i], offset);
         offset += 2;
      }
      i++;
   }
   set_cursor(offset);
}
```

What can be happening in my code?
Note: I'm following the example on this site: https://dev.to/frosnerd/writing-my-own-boot-loader-3mld

Comment: Are you sure that the section of your image containing string literals has been properly loaded into memory by your bootloader, and at the correct address?

Comment: yes, i can write the characters using the print_char() function, however the print_string() function takes the string variable as null and i think it's the function call

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "receives as null".  It is a null pointer, or it is a non-null pointer which points to a null byte, or what?  What test are you doing to reach this conclusion?

Comment: if I define the string in the function itself, it will be displayed normally

Comment: well, i did a check: if(string[i] == 0){variable is null(i think)}

Comment: Okay so that is a test whether the first byte of `string` is a zero byte.  And if it is, that seems consistent with my theory that the string literals section hasn't been loaded.  When you "define the string in the function itself", do you do it via `const char *string = "Hello";` or `const char string[] = "Hello";`?  If the latter works, that's also consistent, because now it's not a string literal.

Comment: Specifically, in the `load_kernel` code, it is hardcoded to load 2 sectors, i.e. 1024 bytes.  Have you verified that your `kernel.bin` is actually 1024 bytes or less?

Comment: When I try the commands given there, I end up with a `kernel.bin` which is about 128 MB!  Probably I have a different default linker script than the author was using, which is part of the problem - they should have actually written a linker script instead of relying on `-T` to try to hack the layout.  But in particular the `.rodata` with the string literals is one page in (offset 4 KB) so in particular loading 2 sectors will not pick it up.

Comment: did you declare a prototype before main for `void print_string(const char *string)`? Or better move that function up. A function must be declared before using

Comment: @phuclv I wondered about that too, but that should give an 'invalid conversion of pointer to int' warning?

Comment: @MartinJames yes there'll be some warnings but not that one https://godbolt.org/z/edTvjKcxe

Comment: Yeah, the implicit declaration is `int print_string();` with unspecified arguments, so that should actually still work.  At least I don't see how it would cause the claimed failure.

Comment: What happens if you simplify your function by skipping offset handling, cursor handing and special character handling for now?

Comment: @NateEldredge I do it through the second option: ```const char string[] = "Hello!";```, my kernel.bin file is 8kb, I think this is it, thanks

Comment: @phuclv yes, i declared the function in video.h and includes the library in main.c, the compiler and the linker don't give me any kind of warning or note

Comment: and I'm using win10 and mingw to do the builds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing discussion from comments:

The bootloader code in this example (not in the question but in the linked site) is hardcoded to load the kernel by reading 2 sectors from the disk.  So this will only work if the kernel image is less than 1 KB in size.  With your modified code, your image turned out to be more than 1 KB (8 KB in fact).  So you weren't loading all of it, and in particular you weren't loading the part of the image that contained your string literal.  Thus when you accessed it, you got the contents of uninitialized memory, which apparently began with a zero byte, giving you the equivalent of an empty string.

You'll need to keep track of the size of your kernel image as you write more code and keep the bootloader in sync: look at the `mov dh, 2` following `load_kernel` and replace 2 by the appropriate number of 512-byte sectors.  For a more serious project, you'd want to come up with a more robust mechanism: e.g. the first sector of the kernel image could contain a header which specifies how many more sectors to read.

Most compiler and linker setups will place string literals into a read-only data section (e.g. `.rodata`), separate from the code section (`.text`), and will arrange for each section to occupy a second set of 4 KB pages, so that page-granular memory permissions can be set accordingly (read and execute for `.text`, read and no execute for `.rodata`).  So even if your code and data could have fit in 1 KB, the need to put the code and data on separate pages is likely what accounts for the 8 KB file size (2 * 4 KB).  If you add read-write data (e.g. a global variable which isn't `const`), you'll probably see another 4 KB increase.